# All combinations of putting characters in string

Tags: python, string

I am trying to do something where I have a word lets say "spark" and I am finding all the possible arrangements of it with "*" in the word. For example "S****", "SPAR*", "SP*R*". Any ideas on how I could do that in python

Comment: Hello, it seems your third example has a formatting issue due to markdown italics by the asterisks. You can escape the asterisks with a "\" like SP\\*R\\*

Comment: @MikeXydas I already edited it to fix that.  Refresh the page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
import itertools
s = "SPARK"
r = ["".join(c if x else '*' for c, x in zip(s, t)) \
     for t in itertools.product((True, False), repeat=len(s))]
```

This gives `r` the following value:

```
['SPARK', 'SPAR*', 'SPA*K', 'SPA**', 'SP*RK', 'SP*R*', 'SP**K',
 'SP***', 'S*ARK', 'S*AR*', 'S*A*K', 'S*A**', 'S**RK', 'S**R*',
 'S***K', 'S****', '*PARK', '*PAR*', '*PA*K', '*PA**', '*P*RK',
 '***RK', '***R*', '****K', '*****']
```

This works as follows:  The top level is a list comprehension.  The outer loop of the comprehension uses `itertools.product`, which produces an iterable containeing tuples of `True` and `False` values.  Each tuple corresponds to an entry in the final result, where a `True` value corresponds to a letter from `s` and a `False` value corresponds to `'*'`.

The inner loop produces a list of single characters.  It iterates over `zip(s, t)`, which pairs up the letters of `s` with the `True`/`False` values in the tuple `t`.  For each pair, if `x` (the value from `t`) is `True`, it selects `c` (the letter from `s`).  Otherwise it selects `'*'`.

The letters in each list of single characters are joined into strings with `"".join(...)`.

Comment: Thanks it works but could you explain how this works it's a lot in a few lines

Comment: @PythonyJavay Ok, I added a description.  Let me know if it makes sense.